# How to convert strings in an CSV file to integers

Tags: python, csv

Trying to add a column in a CVS file. They are listed as strings but are numbers and I need to find the total but convert to integers first.

```
import csv
filename = open('sales.csv','r')
file = csv.DictReader(filename)
sales = []

for col in file:
    sales.append(col['sales'])
print(sales)
```

Have written this but stuck on converting the strings and using the sum function.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend looking at `pandas` instead for this type of work, but

```
import csv
sales = []
with open('sales.csv') as f:
    reader  = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        val = float(row['sales'])  # convert to a number; use int() if you don't have decimals
        sales.append(val)
print(sum(sales))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to consider doing all data type conversions as a single step and then working with the data:

```py
import csv
import decimal  # You should generally use decimal instead of float for currency

sales_records = []
with open('sales.csv') as sales_file:
    sales_reader = csv.DictReader(sales_file)
    for row in sales_reader:
        typed_record = {
            'label': row['label'],  # for example
            'sales': int(row['sales']),
            'price': decimal.Decimal(row['price']),  # for example
        }
        sales_records.append(typed_record)

sales_total = sum([record['sales'] for record in sales_records])
price_total = sum([record['price'] for record in sales_records])
```

UPDATE: adding a line by line breakdown below:

import some packages that we need:

```py
import csv
import decimal
```

create an empty list to hold our records:

```py
sales_records = []
```

open the file using a "context manager" to ensure that it is closed when we're done with it (it's nice to the rest of our computer and our program)

```py
with open('sales.csv') as sales_file:
    ... # everything indented inside this "with" is while the file is open
```

create a csv reader that gives us rows from the file as dictionaries instead of one long string:

```py
sales_reader = csv.DictReader(sales_file)
```

go through the row dictionaries of the file, one at a time:

```py
for row in sales_reader:
    ... # everything here applies to a single row
```

create a new dictionary (called typed_record) for each row

```py
typed_record = {
   ... # keys and values for the dictionary here as 'key': value,
}
```

take a column called "label" in our row and put it directly to the new dictionary:

```py
'label': row['label'],
```

take a column called "sales" in our row, convert it to an int and put it in the new dictionary:

```py
'sales': int(row['sales']),
```

take a column called "price" in our row, convert it to a Decimal and put it in the new dictionary:

```py
'price': decimal.Decimal(row['price']),
```

add the new dictionary to our list of all records:

```py
sales_records.append(typed_record)
```

The last two lines, do two things at once:

first, convert the list of dictionary records into a list of just one value (this is called a "list comprehension" in Python and is a very powerful tool:

```py
[record['sales'] for record in sales_records]]
```

then, we sum up all of those values:

```py
sales_total=sum(...)
```

Comment: thank you, have no idea what all this means yet!

Comment: updated with a line-by-line breakdown